# Key value pairs in ruby, array vs. hash

Tags: ruby

Which is a better practice to store key-value pairs?

An array:

```
class A
  DEFAULTS = [ONE = 1, TWO = 2]
end
```

Or a hash:

```
class A
  DEFAULTS = {'ONE' => 1, 'TWO' => 2 }
end
```

Comment: how would you access the values in the array?

Comment: `A::ONE`  and  `A::TWO`, which I think is kinda awkward.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The two code snippets do *completely different things*. I literally cannot imagine a single situation where it would make sense to choose between the two. Also, that first one is *severely* obfuscated code, and anybody who writes such code should be fired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which is a better practice?

TL;DR You probably want a hash.

---

Your first example looks like keys and values, but it is actually equivalent to:

```
class A
  ONE = 1
  TWO = 2
  DEFAULTS = [ONE, TWO]
end
```

So you are creating three constants:

```
A.constants #=> [:DEFAULTS, :ONE, :TWO]

A::ONE #=> 1
A::TWO #=> 2
A::DEFAULTS #=> [1, 2]
```

And you have to access the array values via indices `0` and `1`:

```
A::DEFAULTS[0] #=> 1
A::DEFAULTS[1] #=> 2
```

---

The second one creates just one constant

```
A.constants #=> [:DEFAULTS]

A::DEFAULTS #=> {"ONE" => 1, "TWO" => 2 }
```

And you can access the values via keys `'ONE'` and `'TWO'`:

```
A::DEFAULTS['ONE'] #=> 1
A::DEFAULTS['TWO'] #=> 2
```

---

A third option is to use a module for namespacing:

```
class A
  module DEFAULTS
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
  end
end
```

Which creates nested constants:

```
A.constants #=> [:DEFAULTS]

A::DEFAULTS #=> A::DEFAULTS

A::DEFAULTS.constants #=> [:ONE, :TWO]

A::DEFAULTS::ONE #=> 1
A::DEFAULTS::TWO #=> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes absolutely no sense whatsoever to ask "which is the better practice", because they do *completely different things*.

The first code snippet

- creates a constant named `TWO` and assigns the value `2` to it
- creates a constant named `ONE` and assigns the value `1` to it
- creates a constant named `DEFAULTS` and assigns the value `[1, 2]` to it

The second code snippet

- creates a constant named `DEFAULTS` and assigns the value `{ 'ONE' => 1, 'TWO' => 2 }` to it

The two code snippets have literally nothing in common. There cannot ever be a situation where you would have a choice of using one or the other.

Comment: I understand that but I meant for the purpose of storing key-value pairs.

Comment: The first code snippet *doesn't store key-value pairs*. **At all**. It makes absolutely no sense whatsoever to compare those two code snippets for the purpose of storing key-value pairs, because one of them doesn't store key-value pairs. The first snippet is just an extremely obfuscated way of writing `ONE = 1; TWO = 2; DEFAULTS = [1, 2]`.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Your "obfuscation" argument is probably valid or this very simple example. However, the pattern can be used to implement a simple static enum. And for that, it's not that obfuscated at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't quite understand how the first one works.

In this case you create:

- class A
- A::DEFAULTS == `[1, 2]`
- A::ONE
- A::TWO

So expression `DEFAULTS = [ONE = 1, TWO = 2]` does not make much sense.

It equals to

```
class A
  DEFAULTS = [1, 2]
  ONE = 1
  B = 2
end
```

So you need to decide how you wanna access those constants: via `A::ONE` or via `A::DEFAULTS['ONE']`

P.S. I recommend you to read about Ruby modules (you can call them namespeces if you like). This is REALLY important